# ManyToMany find not existin elements in relation table (A_B Table)

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have a manytomany relation with 0..* cardinality on one side. i want to query the relation table.
I found the following website : [#2. Find all articles that have no tags assigned](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/) But the query donot work.

```
String hql = "select a from Article a " +
            "left join a.tags t " +
            "group by a " +
            "having count(t)=0";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Article> articles = query.list();
```

When i use this query I get an error that is telling that group by elements are not defined correctly in select statement.

here is an example. Lets say I have Articles table and Tags table relation table generated by hibernate is Articles_Tags. I want to find articles which do not have any tags.

how can i use relation table in hql to find all Articles that do not have tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is invalid.

But this one should do:

```
select a from Article a 
left join a.tags t 
where t.id is null
```

Comment: interestingly i found this invalid query on hibernate FAQ site  as well . [https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-TipsAndTricks#How_can_I_place_a_condition_upon_a_collection_size](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-TipsAndTricks#How_can_I_place_a_condition_upon_a_collection_size)